# What happen in the partition when I uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall

If I installed Ubuntu from inside Windows, and now I want to uninstall it, what happen with the partition in my disk? will it be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Wubi stores its data in one or more files. The file(s), which are as big as your installation, will be deleted. This will remove:

- Your files in your home folder
- Your Ubuntu programs, and any Windows programs you installed **in Ubuntu** using WINE.
- If you are using SSH or PGP keys, they will be removed unless you make a backup.
- The Ubuntu operating system, and *its bootloader*.
- The loopback partition stored in the file for Wubi. It is important to note that *this is a file with a "virtual" partition, not an actual partition on your disk*.

These won't be destroyed:

- Windows programs installed in Windows
- Documents in your My Documents folder, or any documents/settings made on Windows. This includes, on Vista or higher, any files within your user's folder.
- Windows itself.
- The Windows bootloader.
- Anything you put in `/host` on Ubuntu as that is just a reference to your Windows disk.
- Your Windows partition or any other actual partitions on your disk.

Since you used Wubi, the disk space given to Ubuntu will be automatically reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that nothing is going to happen, I believe you can go into that partition (through Windows) and just extend your primary partition therefore giving you that "space" back...what were you trying to do? Uninstall Ubuntu completely?

Comment: The OP installed Ubuntu from *within Windows* and so has used Wubi.